# Make [taps] a synonym of [faucet]

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

[taps](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/taps) 76 questions, all about [faucet](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/faucet) (540 questions). This is a well known (at least American) colloquialism.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for posting. I've approved the synonym from [taps](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/taps) to [faucet](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/faucet).